# Compare items in list with nested for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have a list of URLs in an open CSV which I have ordered alphabetically, and now I would like to iterate through the list and check for duplicate URLs. In a second step, the duplicate should then be removed from the list, but I am currently stuck on the checking part which I have tried to solve with a nested for-loop as follows:

```
for i in short_urls:
    first_url = i
    for s in short_urls:
        second_url = s
    if i == s:
       print "duplicate"
    else:
       print "all good"
```

The `print` statements will obviously be replaced once the nested for-loop is working. Currently, the list contains a few duplicates, but my nested loop does not seem to work correctly as it does not recognise any of the duplicates.

My question is: are there better ways to do perform this exercise, and what is the problem with the current nested for-loop?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Indentation.  If something is not intended to the same level as your loop, it is not inside the loop.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `first_url = i`?

Comment: For that matter, second_url = s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, your method is faulty, even if you indent the `if/else` block correctly. For instance, imagine if you had `[1, 2, 3]` as `short_urls` for the sake of argument. The outer `for` loop will pick out `1` to compare to the list against. It will *think* it's finding a duplicate when in the inner `for` loop it encounters the first element, a `1` as well. Essentially, every element will be tagged as a duplicate and if you plan on removing duplicates, you'll end up with an empty list.

The better solution is to call `set(short_urls)` to get a `set` of your urls with the duplicates removed. If you want a `list` (as opposed to a `set`) of urls with the duplicates removed, you can convert the `set` back into a `list` with `list(set(short_urls))`.

In other words:

```
short_urls = ['google.com', 'twitter.com', 'google.com']
duplicates_removed_list = list(set(short_urls))
print duplicates_removed_list # Prints ['google.com', 'twitter.com']
```

Comment: I already tried your first suggestion; it leads to the loop running infinitely. How would you exactly call the `set(short_urls)`? Not sure I fully understand it yet.

Comment: If `short_urls` is a `list`, you can literally just do `set(short_urls)` and you'll get a `set` of the original `list`. A `set` is a collection with no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
if i == s:
```

is not inside the second for loop. You missed an indentation

```
for i in short_urls:
    first_url = i
    for s in short_urls:
        second_url = s
        if i == s:
           print "duplicate"
        else:
           print "all good"
```

EDIT: Also you are comparing every element of an array with every element of the same array. This means compare the element at position 0 with the element at postion 0, which is obviously the same.
What you need to do is starting the second for at the position after that reached in the first for.

Comment: See my comment on the previous answer: doing this leads to an infinite loop for some reason.